# Как разрешить гостю ходить по страницам Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Юзаю авторизацию из коробки.

Создал контролер OrderController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderController extends Controller {
    public function order() {
        return view('order');
    }
}
```

в роуте

```
Route::get('/order', 'OrderController@order')
```

Пробовал ещё вот так, но не работает:

```
Route::get('/order', 'OrderController@order')->middleware('guest');
```

В какую сторону капать? заранее спасибо Вам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в принципе, вот решение данной проблемы

```
Route::get('/order', function () {
    return view('order');
});
```